# Promise chaining returning undefine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am trying to do promise chaining, but I am getting `undefined` for a part in my chain and I am unsure why. The issue seems to be when I am using `serviceFactory.GetProjectManager()`. When I return that it doesn't seem to be returning a promise, but instead automatically goes into the next `.then()` with a resolved value of `undefined`.

If `GetProjectManager` returns a string and I return that from the function call won't it wrap it in a promise and be passed to the next promise chain?

```
  dataFactory.GetProject()
    .then(function(result){
        return result.Response.ProjectId;
    }).then(function(projectId){
        return serviceFactory.GetProjectManager(projectId);
    })
    .then(function(result){
        //GET UNDEFINED HERE <---------
    })
    .catch(function(error){

    });
```

If I write the code like below, then it will return the right value in the callback, but I do not want to use callbacks I want to use flattened promise chaining.

```
dataFactory.GetProject()
    .then(function(result){
        return result.Response.ProjectId;
    }).then(function(projectId){
        serviceFactory.GetProjectManager(projectId
            ,function(result){
                //Returns Project Manager Here <----
            }
            ,function(error){

        });
    })
    .catch(function(error){

    });
```

Comment: Does serviceFactory.GetProjectManager return a promise, or does it just accept a callback as an argument?

Comment: It only accepts a callback, I guess that must be the reason why promise chaining doesn't work?

Comment: Good guess @FilipJuristovski

Comment: Exactly. Are you able to modify that function to return a promise? If you can then great, if not then you can make a wrapper function that returns a promise so you can still use chaining.

Comment: I cannot modify the function to return a promise, so how do I make this wrapper function that returns a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out in the comments, `GetProjectManager` seems to accept a callback (and return `undefined`) rather than returning a Promise.

You can wrap your original callback-based function into a function that returns a promise, and call that instead:

```js
function GetProjectManagerAsync (serviceFactory, projectId) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        serviceFactory.GetProjectManager(projectId, resolve, reject)
    })
}

dataFactory.GetProject()
    .then(function(result){
        return result.Response.ProjectId
    })
    .then(function (projectId){
        return GetProjectManagerAsync(serviceFactory, projectId)
    })
    .then(function (projectManager) {
        // do something neat with `projectManager`
    })
    .catch(function (error){
        throw error // or do real error handling
    })
```

There are also great libraries that will do this for you automatically, like [**Thenify**](https://github.com/thenables/thenify).

**Edit:** Thanks [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) for pointed out that Angular.js promises would make more sense here.

Comment: Notice that the OP is likely to use Angular promises not the native implemenation